# Installing mod_wsgi on WAMP server running on Windows 7

Tags: python, apache, windows-7, wamp, mod-wsgi

I downloaded mod_wsgi from the [following location](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for apache 2.2 and python 2.7 (64bit). (I'm trying to get django to run on my computer).

Whenever I add the following line:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Apache fails to start up. Can anyone tell me what the issue might be?

Comment: Are you sure you have a `mod_wsgi.so` in your modules directory?

Comment: And what error does apache give you when you try to start it?

Comment: Yes, the mod_wsgi.so file is in my modules directory. The wamp icon just stays yellow and doesn't turn green. When I take out the module it turns green. When I try and select the module from "Apache Modules" drop down, I get the following error: "Could no execute menu item (internal error) [exception] could not perform service action: The service has not been started"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are the following things you need to do to setup Apache for Django. I assume you are using Python 2.7 (**32-bit**) on Windows (**32-bit**) with WAMP server (**32-bits**) installed.

1. [Download](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list) mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so. Or download your respective .so compatible file
2. Change its name to `mod_wsgi.so` and copy it to `/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache22/modules` on Windows.
3. Open `httpd.conf` using Admin rights. Now, you will find a list of lines with `LoadModule ...`. Just add `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` to that list.

   Your are partially done.. you can restart the apache and shouldn't find any errors.
4. Now you need to link it to your Django project.
5. In your Django project root folder, add `apache` folder and create `django.wsgi` (don't change this name) and `apache_mydjango.conf`.
6. In `httpd.conf` add the following line at the bottom of the page.

   `Include "d:/projects/mysite/apache_django_wsgi.conf"`

Open `django.wsgi` and add the following lines:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('d:/projects/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Open `apache_djang_wsgi.conf` and add:

```
Alias /images/ "d:/projects/mysite/templates/images/"
<Directory "d:/projects/mysite/images>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "d:/projects/mysite/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "d:/projects/mysite/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot d:/projects/mysite
    ServerName 127.0.0.1

</VirtualHost>
```

Note:

I am assuming your Django project hierarchy is something like this:

```
mysite/
        mysite/
                 settings.py
                 urls.py, wsgi.py.
        manage.py
        <apache> / apache_django_wsgi.conf, django.wsgi
```

**Best tutorial links:**

1. [port25.technet.com | Published my microsoft.](http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-86-46-PDFs/8637.InstallingApacheonWindows.pdf)
2. [mod_wsgi Quick Install guide](http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-86-46-PDFs/8637.InstallingApacheonWindows.pdf)
3. [Django site](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi)
4. [Django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)

*Actually I don't understand why people are unable to fix it. I've seen lots of questions on it here and I even posted few...So, I thought to write a initial setup version directly as answer*

Comment: I've done a lot of that stuff already. I basically can't make it past step 3. My apache doesn't restart successfully... Ideas?

Comment: Lets clarify one thing first then. The mod_wsgi.so you grabbed requires a 64 bit Apache and a 64 bit Python. The one this answer mentions requires a 32 bit Apache and a 32 bit Python. What versions of Apache and Python do you have installed? Are they 32 or 64 bit? You must use the same for all three components, Apache, Python and mod_wsgi.so, you can't mix 32 and 64 bit versions. On other thing you must do right that this answer doesn't cover, is that you must have installed Python for all users and not just the user you installed it as.

Comment: I have checked that everything is indeed 64bit. I'm not quite sure how to make sure that it's installed for all users however. How would I do this?

Comment: How did you install Python in the first place? The GUI based installer, or a batch installer. In the GUI you need to have specifically selected install for all users on one of the screens. If the batch installer, then it will only install for current user unless you change on of the batch files. I think you can tell if system wide by looking for the Python entries in system wide registry.

Comment: I reinstalled python and that fixed it. I don't think it was installed for all users. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Surya, it works perfectly, but it renders the rest of the localhost sites inaccessible. For example if I go to http://localhost/cart I get a 404 error for a PHP cart installation. Any ideas?

Comment: @AmitG probably there isn't any handler for that endpoint.. I can't comment without clear information

Comment: @Surya, I created a question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505796/django-mod-wsgi-wamp-with-php. If you get around to it, I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following websites for the unofficial windows binaries for python extensions
http://www.kaij.org/blog/?p=123
https://github.com/kirang89/pycrumbs/pull/28

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is using this and doesn't spot it, there is an inconsistency in the steps.  In Step 5 it refers to the filename `apache_mydjango.conf`

In Step 6 it refers to the filename `apache_django_wsgi.conf`

These should obviously both be the same name - it doesn't matter which way round you go for - but I spent a while trying to figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Olly's correction, there is another error in Step6:
Instead of

```
Include "d:/projects/mysite/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

it should be

```
Include "d:/projects/mysite/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

I made all the steps and now can't start Apache Server anymore. The Wamp Image is red. I could restart Apache as described in Step 3.

Answer (score 0):

**How I configured Apache + Django + venv**

For it to work you need 3 things:

1. install `mod_wsgi` on python and apache
2. setup `httpd.conf` on apache
3. configure python script (usually wsgi.py) that is loaded by `mod_wsgi` and in turn loads your python app

**1.** Is described well enough in the official doc (I used the pip method). Just unpack apache distro (ApacheHaus worked for me, but **not** Apache Lounge, it missed some headers I think) to a **standard** place like `C:\` **or** set env var `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` to its dir. You'll need Visual Studio Build Tools **or** binary distribution of mod_wsgi. Then `pip install` it.

**2.** In httpd.conf add:

```
LoadFile ".../pythonXY/pythonXY.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module ".../mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cpXY-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome ".../pythonXY"
WSGIScriptAlias / "...\wsgi.py"
```

Here `LoadFile` may be necessary if Python isn't installed the standard way. Better to include.
`WSGIPythonHome` directive should point to main python distro (not **venv** as is usually said), because **mod_wsgi** may be somewhat not working properly. For instance now `WSGIPythonPath` is doing nothing at all. Alternatively, you can set PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME env vars accordingly.

*Now you can monitor error log of apache (inside its log folder by default).
In case of failures apache will print mod_wsgi configuration (meaning it is installed, but couldn't start python) and/or python errors if it managed to start.*

**3.** Inside your python script (`wsgy.py`) you'll need to provide function **"application"** (so is `mod_wsgi` usually compiled) which starts your app. But first point python to the modules and packages it will use, your own as well, right in the script with `sys.path` or `site.addsitedir`. Django's wsgi.py is good, just prepend all path conf there.

Answer (score -1):

Only for users running windows 64 versions.

I have created wsgi. Now you only need to install python and run apache.
The configurations have already been set in the package. Just download the package and follow the instructions from 'Steps to follow.txt file' present in package.

You dont need to download python and apache and mod_wsgi.so from anywhere. I have compiled the so file, and compatible python and apache2 versions. So that you are ready to deploy. 
Just that in apache config the document root has been set to cgi-bin folder present inside Apache2.

Package can be downloaded from [Zip package](https://github.com/guptaaditya/Python-Apache-mod_wsgi-package/blob/master/apache-python-wsgisosetup.zip)

[Instructions and package usage](https://github.com/guptaaditya/Python-Apache-mod_wsgi-package)