# Django/mod_wsgi WAMP with PHP

Tags: php, django, apache, wamp, wampserver

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602653/installing-mod-wsgi-on-wamp-server-running-on-windows-7/11602894?noredirect=1#comment30631187_11602894) and managed to make Python with a Django installation work perfectly, but it seems to have rendered all the locally hosted PHP sites inaccessible returning a 404 error.

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

#This is placed right after the rule for <Directory "f:/WAMP/www/">
<Directory "f:/WAMP/www/python">
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#This is placed at the end of the file
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "f:/WAMP/alias/*"
Include "F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

**apache_django_wsgi.conf**

```
Alias /python/images/ "F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/images"
<Directory "F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/images">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /python "F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot f:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/
ServerName 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>
```

**django.wsgi**

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('F:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sandbox.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

PHP only renders when I comment out the lastline from httpd.conf.

Comment: This line `DocumentRoot f:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/` is going to send everything to that directory. I think you'll need another virtual host to run PHP.

Comment: I suspected that, is there a way to localize that specific rule to just the python/django directory? Setting up multiple virtual hosts seems much less efficient.

Comment: Not inefficient, it's the way all apache sites work. You'll need to edit your hosts file and make 2 sites called python.dev and php.dev. Then make that the `ServerName` for the python vhost and php vhost respectively.

Comment: If I understand correctly, as WAMP/www is currenly the PHP localhost, I should place the Python folder into a separate independent directory and update the virtual hosts? Would it be possible for you to create the VirtualHost configurations as an answer? I'm unsure about how I can enable Python without modifying the location of the current PHP www folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another virtual host if you're going to set the `DocumentRoot`:

```
# This is for PHP
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot f:/WAMP/www/
ServerName local.php.dev
</VirtualHost>

# This is for your Django stuff
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot f:/WAMP/www/python/sandbox/
ServerName local.py.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, as it is now, all the local requests are being sent to the python sandbox.

Note that you'll need to have several hosts pointing locally.