# Installing mod_wsgi for wampserver

Tags: python, apache, wampserver

I am trying to install the mod_wsgi.so for wampserver.
I am using python 3.4 (64 bits). I downloaded the mod_wsgi zip file for 64 bits and have the 64 bit wampserver.

I extracted the file mod_wsgi.so from the downloaded zip file. There was no need to rename the file since the file was already named correctly. I transferred the file to wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.4/modules and then edited the "httpd.conf" file on line 71 with
"LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"

I found this reference on stackflow that I used - [Installing mod_wsgi on WAMP server running on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602653/installing-mod-wsgi-on-wamp-server-running-on-windows-7)

I also found several other references all with the same instructions. My wampserver will not go from orange to green with the module load in the httpd.conf - I am wondering if maybe there is different instructions for python 3.4 since all references are pointing to ver 2,7.

I have uninstalled python and reinstalled python making sure I have access for all users - I have verified that all version of all software is 64 bit and I am running a 64 bit machine.

Comment: You can check for the error in log files or try to find it in windows events