# Getting error when deploy django project on apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying django project on Apache using mod_wsgi.
I have followed [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602653/installing-mod-wsgi-on-wamp-server-running-on-windows-7)step by step to setup this on Windows_Server_2008_R2 which is equivalent of windows 7.

I am getting error :

> no module named project_name.settings

where **project_name** is my app name.

Please let me know if more info needs to be provided.

Comment: Your `PYTHONPATH` is not set to your project folder.

Comment: without wsgi when i use manage.py runserver it works fine, so it must not be due to pythonpath

Comment: It is. The current working directory is usually in the `PYTHONPATH` implicitly. mod_wgsi is not running from that path. So, set `WSGIPythonPath` in the Apache config!